# Rails pages_controller_spec.rb test shouldn't be failing but is, error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, routes

Have been following Rails Tutorial by Michael Hart
rails version 3.0 on mac OS X 10.7

$ rspec spec/

```
......FF

Failures:

  1) PagesController GET 'help' should be successful
     Failure/Error: get 'help'
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"help"}
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:45:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) PagesController GET 'help' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: get 'help'
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"help"}
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:49:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.14686 seconds
8 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:44 # PagesController GET 'help' should be successful
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:48 # PagesController GET 'help' should have the right title
```

The test looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title",
      :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should have_selector("title",
      :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'about'
      response.should have_selector("title",
      :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'help'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'help'
      response.should be_success
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'help'
      response.should have_selector("title",
      :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
    end
  end
end
```

And I have in pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @title = "Home"
  end

  def contact
    @title = "Contact"
  end

  def about
    @title = "About"
  end

  def help
    @title = "Help"
  end

end
```

And in routes.rb I have

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "pages/home"
  get "pages/contact"
  get "pages/about"
  get "pages/help"
end
```

And of course I also created a help.html.erb page in app/views/pages
The strange thing is when I run rails server and go to localhost:3000/pages/help I get the proper page with the proper title, making it appear as if the test should've passed, yet it doesn't. Additionally the contact, home, and about tests pass but when I just now added the help it doesn't for some unknown reason. This is really bugging me out, what is the simple solution I have overlooked that it driving me insane?

Comment: For some reason my help.html.erb file is 275 bytes, while my about, contact, and home .html.erb pages are all 2kb, despite the fact they are almost the exact same number of characters in each. This surely has something to do with help.html.erb not functioning when tested. Also the document type for help is a TextMate Document while the others just say "Document". Strange.. ?

Comment: I think you're on the right track -- there's nothing in the code that would appear to fail. I'd try deleting and recreating the help.html.erb file.

Comment: thanks for the idea, unfortunately it didn't help. It especially strange that its giving me an error that rake routes is then contradicting as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917201/my-computer-hates-me

Comment: It's not surprising your other question was down-voted. Don't use sarcastic titles for questions or cursing -- it's frowned upon heavily. Why don't you post your code to github and link to it -- I'll take a look for you and get you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't appropriate, I've pushed it up here https://github.com/lasernite/sample_app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloaded your code and ran:

```
........
8 examples, 0 failures
Finished in 0.18184 seconds
```

It is running the GET 'help', so I think you're running this in autotest and it is not reloading. Possible?

Comment: Thank-you, quit terminal and opened and new window and everything is running fine. Simplicity is magical.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine. The issue is that your previous code got cached. By quitting terminal and opening a new window, you are effectively clearing your cache. You might run into the same issues if you don't turn off caching in the test environment. Go to `config/environments/test.rb` and change `config.cache_classes = true` to `config.cache_classes = false`